# How to get current time in milliseconds in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I want to debug a slow function in Rascal, to find out why it is slow. To do this, I want to save the system time in milliseconds at certain locations so I can measure the time taken by certain parts of the code.

I have looked at the DateTime module (http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/DateTime/DateTime.html), but it does not seem easy to compute time differences this way.
Is there any better way?

Comment: I'd also use the profiler, but the - operator to subtract datetime values is also helpful.

Comment: Agreed, if you use the - operator to subtract one datetime from another you will get back a Duration value, and this includes the number of milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc between the two datetime values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a buildin profiler in rascal, that does function and statement level profiling. You can enable it with `:set profiling true` in the repl.

If you want to do benchmarking, take a look at `util:;Benchmark`